# How does the Wifi router know which PC to forward a request to, when some PC is running a server program like Apache/IIS?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port-forwarding, webserver, websocket

I was studying about socket programming. What I understood is that it is a combination of an IP Address and a Port number. Now suppose I have a listener running on my PC, which is connected to Wifi. The requests to this listener over Internet should come to a public IP address and port number combination. There may be multiple PC's connected to the Wifi I am connected to. When a request comes to the Wifi router, how would it know which PC should it be forwarded to in the Wifi LAN?

When I am chatting on Facebook, or when I have Fb opened in a browser, while connected to internet via a Wifi connection, how does the server 'push' the chat msgs and notifications to me? Will it not face a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a request comes to the Wifi router, how would it know which PC should it be forwarded to in the Wifi LAN?

It does not know. The traffic will be dropped or rejected.

That’s why you need port forwarding if you want to host externally accessible servers behind a **NAT router**. Of course, the wireless network could also be “directly connected to the Internet”, without NAT. Some universities do/did this. And with IPv6, we’re thankfully getting back there.

> When I am chatting on Facebook, or when I have Fb opened in a browser, while connected to internet via a Wifi connection, how does the server 'push' the chat msgs and notifications to me?

It does not “actively” push. It sends data in response to a request your browser sends. This uses an established TCP connection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Daniel B.
For the second part of the question, your answer says TCP connection is used. Is it so that the browser is continuously sending requests to server? I ask that because the notifications and chat messages get delivered almost instantly. For that to happen, there would be a polling mechanism.

When I read about web sockets, it said that web sockets uses an established connection, using which the server can send data to client. I thought it would be able to 'actively' send data whenever required. That was told as a better alternative to polling.

Comment: There are multiple possibilities like WebSockets, Server Sent Events and Long Polling. All involve a TCP connection that is initiated by the browser. That’s the important part. Because TCP connections are bidirectional, both ends can send unrequested data.